# How to reduce the size of a React Native iOS application?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native, fonts

I have created a React Native application for iOS and Android. It is using some custom fonts. Please check the size of the folders :

1. Font folder - 18mb
2. Assets folder - 1mb
3. coding files - 118kb

This is in my package.json file.

[image: first image]

[image: Packge json file 2nd image]

But my complete app is showing on the app store is around 65.5mb and after download it's size is showing around 77.5 MB.

Can anyone suggest me what should I do to reduce my iOS application size? These libraries are necessary for different functionalities of my application. Please help me to reduce the size of the app. There are multiple tutorials available to reduce android application size but how can I reduce my iOS application size.

Also, I have tried to minimize the size of the .otf file but not find any tool or website that works for a mobile app.

Thank you.

Comment: I created new app with react-native init command and then after run pod install my app size is 19 mb approx. It is just newly created app but when I install react-native firebase it size is 44mb. Can any one suggest me for it.

Comment: Can anyone find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I checked my .ttf files and they are in approx 8mbs. I do search on google and download the font file in KBS and it reduces my application size less than 50%.
I hope this answer work for any other person. 
Thanks

Comment: what tool did you use to inspect the app size? Is any other option other than an inspector in android studio?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure this in Android:

- Open up android/app/build.gradle
- Set def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true this would enable Progaurd to compress the Java Bytecode. This reduces the app size by a tad bit
- Set def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true . Android devices support two major device artitectures armebi and x86. By default RN builds the native librariers for both these artitectures into the same apk.

Now, when you build a release, it doesn't contain unnecesary files and assets.

For iOS you can use bitcode to reduce the size. 
Check this: https://agostini.tech/2019/06/02/reduce-your-app-size-with-app-thinning/

For more information check this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

I hope this was useful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need a solution for iOS.

Comment: Check this: https://agostini.tech/2019/06/02/reduce-your-app-size-with-app-thinning/

Comment: thank you but I have tried these all possible solutions but nothing impact on app size.